# Symfony 4, from a method in custom foo class (src/Utils/foo.php), require_one have no effect

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, require-once

I need to load all classes which are in a specific project directory ("dir1/dir2") for list all method (and only list all method, not use them)

I can list all classes but I can't load them and I don't understand why !

For now, I have only the class faa, in /dir1/dir2/faa.php with some methods.

And in a custom Utils class I did :

```
// in <root_dir>/src/Utils/foo.php
<?php

namespace App\Utils;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelInterface;

class Foo
{

    public $specificCustomDir;

    public function __construct(KernelInterface $kernel)
    {
        // I store the absolute path of the directory where I want load all classes
        $this->specificCustomDir = $kernel->getProjectDir() . "/dir1/dir2";
    }

    public function getClasses(){
        foreach (glob($this->specificCustomDir . "/*.php") as $file)
        {
            dump($file); // Its OK ! I get "/home/.../mysymfoproject/dir1/dir2/faa.php" 

            require_once($file); // It seems OK ! no PHP error, so the path of the file is correct

            $class = basename($file, '.php');

            dump($class); // Its OK ! I get "Faa"

            // the path file is OK 
            // the class name is OK

            // but class_exists return false
            if (class_exists($class))
            {
                dump("test yes"); // KO because the class_exists return false and I don't understand why 
                $obj = new $class;
                foreach(get_class_methods($obj) as $method)
                {
                    // I just want show methods, not use them !
                    dump($method);
                }
            }else{
                dump("class not found ! "); // KO, this message appears !
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I use my Foo class from a symfony controller like this :

```
$foo = new Foo();
$foo->getClasses();
```

I can't list all methods of my Faa class because the class_exists function return false :/

Where is my mistake ? Thanks for some help :)

Comment: Why do you load classes by yourself? Symfony can do that for you, why not use it.

Comment: You are maybe right ! can you show me how ? I insist, I want load classes dynamically (classes which are in a specific custom directory)

Comment: `PSR-4 autoload`

Comment: Apart from totally agreeing with @u_mulder, is your Faa class in a namespace? If so, you will need to specify the full namespace.

Comment: I saw I can use the psr autoload here https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/class_loader.html but I tried, I failed and I didn't understand how use it :/

Comment: @Gordon all classes defined in the dir1/dir2 have namespaces yes

Comment: ... have the same* namespace

Comment: Well, `Faa` is not the same class as `App\Utils\Faa`. You are testing for `Faa`.

Comment: indeed, there are two different classes ;) Foo is the class through which I want load all classes located in the dir1/dir2 directory. Faa is an example class located in dir1/dir2, so my example script must list all methods in the faa class

Comment: Without understand the usecase you are trying to solve, did you have a look into tagged services?

Comment: @user2137454 what I am trying to say is that you will need the pass the fully qualified namespace to `class_exists`